# Using Ajax Button to Filter Django Models

Tags: python, ajax, django, django-models, django-views

I am attempting to make buttons on my website that, when clicked, apply a specific filter to my database of models. The model item I would like to sort is a "Clothes_Item" and I would like to apply various sorts of filters. I just want to get this working on a very basic level and then I'll be able to figure it out from there, so let's just say I want to have a singular button that will display all clothing items with gender = "unisex" (where gender is a field of my Clothes_Item model).

index.html

```
<input class="filter-button" type="button" data="unisex" value="unisex" data_url/>
```

main.js

```
$('.filter-button').on('click', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var element = $(this); //button that was clicked
    $.ajax({
        url : 'filter_clothes/',
        type: 'GET',
        data: { filter_category : element.attr("data") },
});
```

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),
    url(r'filter_clothes/', views.filter_clothes, name='filter_clothes'),
    #more urls...
```

views.py

```
def filter_clothes(request):
    filter_category = request.GET.get("filter_category")
    clothes = Clothes_Item.objects.filter(gender=filter_category)
    return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('index', kwargs={'clothes': clothes}))

def index(request, **kwargs):
    clothes = Clothes_Item.objects.all()
    if 'clothes' in kwargs:
        clothes = kwargs['clohtes']
    if request.user.is_authenticated():
        favorite_clothes_ids = get_favorite_clothes_ids(request)
        return render(request, 'index.html', {'clothes': clothes, 'favorite_clothes_ids': favorite_clothes_ids})
    return render(request, 'index.html', {'clothes': clothes})
```

I'm recieving a "NoReverseMatch at /filter_clothes/" error and I haven't been able to fix this for awhile. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

EDIT: The above issue has been fixed but I didn't completely resolve the issue. The new error is as follows: Reverse for 'index' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{'clothes': ]>}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['$']

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change a regexp pattern for index view in **urls.py**, as it matches just empty string, but you pass `clothes` argument to it. For example, if `clothes` consists of alphanumeric characters, you can change the pattern to `r'^/(?P<clothes>\w+)/$'`

EDIT: 
Instead of filter_clothes view, you could pass a get parameters directly to the index view. So it might look like this:

```
def index(request):
    clothes = Clothes_Item.objects.all()
    filter_category = request.GET.get('filter_category')
    if filter_category:
        clothes = clothes.filter(gender=filter_category)
    if request.user.is_authenticated():
        favorite_clothes_ids = get_favorite_clothes_ids(request)
        return render(request, 'index.html', {'clothes': clothes, 'favorite_clothes_ids': favorite_clothes_ids})
    return render(request, 'index.html', {'clothes': clothes})
```

Comment: clothes is a queryset of Clothes_Item objects so that particular solution wouldnt work in this case.

Comment: Are you trying to pass a queryset in a url tag, e.g. `{% url 'appname:index' queryset %}?

Comment: No, I'm using ajax to send data to a view function.

Comment: The reason for an error is a `reverse` function in `filter_clothes` view. You can pass only string or integer as an argument to a view, as argument is a part of url. I've added a suggested solution to the answer.

Comment: I mean possible solution.

Comment: Your solution worked for the issue I was having so thanks a lot! It makes much more sense to do it in this way. However, the index view still doesn't seem to be displaying the changes. I've already checked to see that the filter is applied correctly, but the changes don't seem to be reflected in the web page. Any thoughts as to why that may be? I don't know if this would impact it, but I have a never_cache decorator on this view to support other elements of my site.

Comment: I can't say for sure. Check your jquery function that populates the page with a new data. Does it replace old clothes items with filtered ones?

Comment: I thought that my view would be altered by the call to the view function from within the ajax. I never specifically did anything within the ajax to hide or show particular elements.

Comment: No, when you use `render` to send a response to ajax, it recieves raw html - the rendered template. You can use done and fail methods to handle the response, here's an example: [link](https://learn.jquery.com/ajax/jquery-ajax-methods/). So, for example, if you have a `<div class="clothes">` element, that contains all clothes items, your `.done()` could be: `.done(function (html) {
$('.clothes').html(html);
})`

Comment: Also you can send JSON or XML responses to ajax (django has a [JsonResponse](https://docs.djangoproject.com/el/1.10/ref/request-response/#jsonresponse-objects) object, that takes a python dictionary as first argument and converts it to JSON response).

Answer (score 2):

Change `url : 'filter_clothes/'` to `url : '/filter_clothes/'`

Comment: It's still giving me an error: 
Reverse for 'index' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{'clothes': <QuerySet [<Clothes_Item: green pants>]>}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['$']

Comment: It seems that changer has solved your original error.  This should solve your new error.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20993598/reverse-for-index-with-arguments-and-keyword-arguments-not-found-0

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, that error was due to the fact that the user had not specified a value for name. Have I not already done this in this line? 
url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'), @PatrickFalvey